# How to capture traffic in monitor mode when you know the password

Tags: wireless-networking, sniffing, network-traffic

I have turned on the monitor mode using `airmon-ng start wlan0` and I can see this when I do `iwconfig`:

```
mon0      IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Now I need to capture encrypted traffic on my LAN. Lets say my wifi's password is `abc12345` how can I capture traffic from all of the devices on my (LAN) network? Feel free to ask me if anything is confusing or stupid in my question.

**Note:** Kindly keep it as non-technical as it can be. I am a complete noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you capture it encrypted and then use a tool to decrypt it after the fact. Assuming your network uses WPA2-PSK security, as most modern home networks do, you need to capture the the "WPA handshake", also known as the "eapol-key exchange", that happens when the client connects to the network (on boot or wake from sleep or after getting disconnected for whatever reason). You need information from that exchange in order to decrypt the packets from that particular connection session of that particular client.

Wireshark provides a way to enter the WPA2-PSK pass phrase of the network, and it will then automatically decrypt the frames from any client session for which it can find the entire WPA handshake in the capture.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help! Exactly what I needed.